# Using leaflet how can you remove old map tiles added by external plugins?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a map with the feature set to change your map tiles in user preferences,  the below function is responsible for changing the map tiles dynamically when the user wants to.

- The actual problem

When I do change the map tiles, for example from CartoDB to OSM in real time, when planning the map viewport, you can see old tiles from CartoDB.

Evidence / Video of this
https://i.gyazo.com/702e8e4875bc89c13f41a132dccb78da.mp4

Another thing I should mention, I'm using "leaflet-providers" plugin, for the simple API of adding the tiles to the map.

I did raise an issue on the github repo about my experience of this, but the issue was closed and the author mentioned that this was indeed a leaflet issue, so I've come here for some leaflet.js advice :)

I am aware of how to remove tile layers already, so I need something a little more specific and in relation to my code, here is what I've tried.

```
//this

self.map.removeLayer(L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap'))

//this?
//self.map.invalidateSize();

//this??
self.map.invalidateSize();
```

```
let self = this;
let mapLayer = self.mapLayer;

if (mapLayer === 'osm') {
    L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap').addTo(self.map);
}
if (mapLayer === 'cartodb') {
    L.tileLayer.provider('CartoDB').addTo(self.map);
}

//attempt to refresh tiles?
self.map._onResize();
self.map.invalidateSize();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is that whenever you call `L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap')`, you get a *new* instance of a Leaflet Tile Layer.

Therefore when you try removing a Layer from the map with `map.removeLayer(L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap'))`, you pass a *new* layer to your `map` instance. Because this new Layer is not yet on the map, nothing happens. In particular, the *previous* Tile Layer remains in place, leading to the situation where you can still see its tiles occasionally.

Simply keep a reference to your initial Layer and use that reference to remove it from the map later on:

```js
var myLayer = L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap');

myLayer.addTo(map);

// Later...
map.removeLayer(myLayer);

// even simpler alternative:
myLayer.remove();
```